Reverse engineering an autoexposure system
So, I want to take some large format images with my neophot 21 microscope. This would be significantly easier 40 years ago, but it’s not 40 years ago, it’s now. This means a few things:

can’t use the film it was originally mainly intended for (Polaroid)
it has aftermarket parts not from the original manufacturer which have zero documentation anywhere I can find
Even if I had documentation, the condition of parts may have deteriorated and it may require compensation
I don’t have the part for it used to make an exposure on a bunch of small sections of the film in sequence, used for this exact purpose of figuring out ideal exposure

The first problem should be solved with just a new film holder. But the other three mean that the exposure controller, is completely unknown in functionality to me. It’s an aftermarket part labeled with the numbers 1-12, instead of DIN values like the original, or ASA values like other aftermarket parts I found on eBay. And the compensation dial on mine literally just has a zero at the top, instead of any indicator of the level of change turning it causes. I can’t assume anything about mine is the same as the other parts I’ve found online, because those aren’t the same as each other, and the relative timings don't match the limited testing I've done on mine. So my only hope is to guess what the autoexposure is supposed to be exposing for at given settings, based on exposing film at different settings, to figure out what the settings actually mean, so I can actually use it.
If I was using a digital camera, this is easy to solve: just compare the average pixel values on the photos, and multiply the speed of the camera by them as a fraction of the max value, and done. When doing this with film, the problem is that film is notorious for bad linearity, reciprocity failure, and generally being a pain. And a large format digital back is $26k, while I acquired this microscope used for 15 dollars, so the investment seems a bit mismatched with that.
So I need to figure out how to account for nonlinearity and reciprocity failure, when trying to calculate the ISO/ASA/DIN values that it’s actually trying to expose for. This is especially a problem when based on the exposure in the online parts, I probably have exposure about 10 stops apart or more from the first to last value. This is realistically about the limit for dynamic range of film in ideal conditions to cover, so I expect that at least a few shots on either side of the settings will be over or under exposed to uselessness.
I’m not sure how I am supposed to do this best, and with the least waste of film.

Film has quite a large dynamic range. Not as large as modern digital cameras, but large. Also, film will bring different contrast/colours/exposure based on the development.
You have two options at this point:

build a "tent" over the place where the film would be placed, and place a DLSR without lens on it, so that you can take a shot using the digital sensor. You will acquire a small fraction of the total surface, but it doesn't matter
place a transparent+satin 3mm PMMA/acrylic or polycarbonate sheet and place it where the film would go (small errors don't matter, you don't need a sharp picture), then in a totally dark room (or under a black tent) place a DSLR in a position so that it can see most of the plate. Most DSLR lenses have 0.45x enlargement factor at minimum focusing distance, so you will be able to get the whole image of the sheet.

In both cases, take a digital shot of the image, while setting all exposure settings of the microscope and the light strength to half way. You can also take multiple shots with various settings.
Once you have a digital shot of the image which would be impressed onto the film, search this website for conversion from digital to film exposure, various questions have been asked about it. Anyway it's easier: for short exposures under 1 second there's no reciprocity, and for nonlinearity you simply increase exposure by 1 stop compared to optimal settings for digital, because digital needs to avoid saturation so it's kept low, while film needs to be brighter to get details in shadows.

“then take 3 shots: 0, +- 2 stops.” Maybe I wasn’t super clear, but my whole problem is that I don’t have any way to find out where any of those would be in terms of settings, because there’s no documentation.

You say it uses "large format film"? those come at 5 euro/dollar per shot at the very minimum, up to 15/shot. You might want to find anything that allows you to avoid film. Anyway, can you post some photos or link to the microscope manual or a page which talks about it? it's something completely abstract so far and I'd like to see where the film goes

The only relevant images would be these two https://ibb.co/yV87x29 https://ibb.co/KwDNbWD. Picture of diagram from manual, which shows a second way to get an image, but I don’t have any of the optics past the red line I drew there. And then a full image of the device I bought, back when I bought it. Dont have a super good image that’s more recent and shows everything(box with cable, and dials on it next to microscope is camera controller) As I said though, there is no documentation on the aftermarket parts, anywhere as far as I can tell.

If 08 is the place where the film goes and it has rails or something to fix a film back to it, why don't you 3D print an adaptor to use a macro lens with a regular DSLR, or a mount for a Raspberry Pi camera? it will extend the machine by maybe 40 cm, of course, but there you have your digital image, and it will be easier than getting film, getting the exposure, developing film. And cheaper.

I’m not sure what you are saying. The area covered by a dslr or other digital camera would be a tiny fraction of the total area intended to be projected on, it wouldn’t be useful.

See if my edit helps.

Hmm, I believe you are making a frame challenge, right? While a digital conversion isn’t anything I am against, it’s not exactly my ideal case either. I could probably try the idea in the first bullet point as a way to reverse engineer exposure without dealing with the issues with reciprocity failure and nonlinearity though.

I'm saying that once you have a exposure settings for the digital camera, then you can convert them to film taking into account the various parameters. At least you have a reference, which is simple: for short exposures under 1 second there's no reciprocity, and for nonlinearity you simply increase exposure by 1 stop because digital needs to avoid saturation so it's kept low, while film needs to keep brighter to get details in shadows. I update the answer.

Procure a working light meter. Procure a plastic funnel that will accommodate the meter. The other end of the funnel should be sized to slip over the microscope's eyepiece. Tape frosted plastic sheet over entrance to the light meter. The meter will now read the intensity of the light traversing the microscope. This type of measuring is called "integrating". This method should prove quite reliable.
Experiment by setting the ISO (ASA) of the meter by guess, you will soon find the required settings. Don't concern yourself with reciprocity failure. Your exposures will likely be short. Reciprocity failure in film is a fall-off of sensitivity when very short or very long exposure times are used. Likely your exposure times will be under 10 minutes so reciprocity failure is likely moot.

“Experiment by setting the ISO (ASA) of the meter by guess, you will soon find the required settings.” How would measuring the eyepiece, which is a completely separate light path from the film, help me figure out the film exposure? At best if there was some way to convert a light value in the eyepiece to the value at the film plane, that would just tell me how much I need to expose, which wouldn’t help because I don’t have the ability to set the exposure.

If you can't adjust exposure, its hopeless. I think you can find a way. Impose neutral density filters, adjust the intensity of light source, adjust the time of exposure, if no other way, by turning off and on the light source. Lots of ways to attack this problem. As to two separate optical systems -- I feel strongly that they are proportional and that an integrated (diffused) reading can do this trick. As an example, high-speed photofinishing printers, used an integrated light meter reading via a separate light path to calculate exposure.

"If you can't adjust exposure, its hopeless." Maybe that wasn't worded well, I can change the settings for automatic exposure calculation, just not the direct length of exposure. However, I do not have the documentation required to figure out what the settings of the automatic exposure actually are, its effectively a few unlabeled dials. While the light would be proportional through the eyepeice, I would have no idea what the proportion is, so it would be the exact same random guessing that I am trying to avoid even if i could directly set the exposure length.

You might not want to bother?
The imaging circle of Polaroid is a heck of a lot larger than 35mm film or a full frame digital, and larger still than a crop format digital camera. So if you're preserving the focal plane of the old adapter then your new images are going to be a tiny crop from the image center.  And digital is probably your easiest way to convert an unknown system as you can just tweak the exposure on the camera until it fits.

I am replacing the large format Polaroid back, with a normal large format sheet film back, not converting to a digital sensor. It might not have been clear but thats what i meant by "first problem should be solved with just a new film holder."
